# Error building GDAL: PROJ_INCLUDE should be defined. PROJ >= 6 is a required dependency

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, gdal

I am trying to get GDAL 3.0.1 to work. Generating the Visual Studio 2017 project was a piece of cake, all I needed was to run `generate_vcxproj.bat`. But now I'm getting an error on this line of `makefile.vc`:

```
!IF !DEFINED(PROJ_INCLUDE)
!ERROR PROJ_INCLUDE should be defined. PROJ >= 6 is a required dependency
!ENDIF
```

What's that all about? If I am meant to define `PROJ_INCLUDE`, what value should it have? Is that even preprocessor define?

Comment: Clearly, someone at GDAL didn't think this through.  UGH!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error is confusing because `PROJ` sounds like shortened *"project"*. But it is, in fact, a dependency on the PROJ library. I installed it through OSGeo as [recommended in installation instructions](https://proj.org/install.html#windows).

After that, fill in the paths to installed libs into `nmake.opt`:

```
# PROJ stuff (required dependency: PROJ >= 6)
PROJ_INCLUDE = -IC:\OSGeo4W64\proj
PROJ_LIBRARY = C:\OSGeo4W64\lib\proj_5_2.lib
```

Comment: I did it as described. It started building, but then I received the "proj.h" No such file or directory message.

Comment: @RogerAlmengor I do not remember how I managed to compile the whole thing. What I do remember is that there were many more issues and it took me 5 hours to get it working. But check the other answer, maybe the path in mine is wrong.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I started building a GDAL application using VS Code (see this post: https://lazyadminblog.blogspot.com/2018/07/how-to-build-gdal-from-source-for.html.). But when I ran my application I received the following message: Th following program cannot be executed, becase gdal302_d.dll was not found (or something along this lines, I have a german version and this is a quick and dirty translation from the original message). In the message it is stated that by reinstalling gdal the problem might be solved. However it did not happen that way.

Comment: Can someone give an updated answer for the PROJ version? Right now if you install OSGeo4 there is no /proj directory and there is also no proj_x_x.lib file

Comment: @justanotherguy I certainly cannot. Just seeing your reply made me sad because I remembered that trying to build this project took so much of my energy that even after I finally made it, I no longer had any energy to do what I wanted to do with it.

Comment: That's unfortunate. The latest OSGeo4 installation doesn't include any of the files mentioned in the answers in this post. I guess I'll have to keep digging.

Answer (score 3):

If I could've comment, it would be one:

I think, you gave an incorrect Include path:

```
PROJ_INCLUDE = -IC:\OSGeo4W64\include
```

would be the correct one.
Also it claims, it needs PROJ version >=6, but it's 5.2 if I'm not mistaken.
Didn't you had problems with inclusion of proj_experimental.h?